# Ctools modals without AJAX

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite, javascript

What's the sanest way to present a Ctools modal to the user while bypassing the normal AJAX workflow? For example, how could I show a completely JavaScript-generated "Are you sure you want to log out?" confirmation prompt to the user in a Ctools modal after the user clicks the "log out" link?

I know I can probably fake a box which would get the same styling as the Ctools modal, but I'd rather avoid silly hacks if not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be possible by invoking `Drupal.CTools.Modal.show` directly. The function takes one argument (the modal-style), which either can be a string pointing to an object on `Drupal.settings` or the style-object itself.

After showing the dialog, it is possible to populate title and content using jQuery:

```
Drupal.CTools.Modal.show('my-modal-style');
$('#modal-title').html('my-title');
$('#modal-content').html('some markup here').scrollTop(0);
Drupal.attachBehaviors();
```

In your PHP code, you need to ensure that ctools `modal.js` and also `misc/ajax.js` gets loaded:

```
drupal_add_js('misc/ajax.js');

ctools_add_js('modal');
ctools_add_css('modal');

// Add your modal style to the settings. You find the defaults in modal.js near the top:
drupal_add_js(array(
  'my-modal-style' => array(
    'modalSize' => array(
      'type' => 'fixed',
      'width' => 250,
      'height' => 250,
    ),
    'closeText' => 'Dismiss',
    'closeImage' => ...
  ),
), 'setting');
```

Comment: Turns out I'm not having a chance to implement this after all, but it'll surely be useful if I run into this problem in the future. Thanks!